# How do I compile cabal?

Tags: archlinux, haskell

I am using `Arch Linux ARM` with `ghc 6.12.3-1` and `gcc 4.7.1-5`. When I try to compile [cabal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cabal-install/0.14.0/cabal-install-0.14.0.tar.gz)[TAR] using:

```
sh bootstrap.sh
```

Error

```
Checking installed packages for ghc-6.12.3...
Cabal-1.14.0 will be downloaded and installed.
transformers-0.3.0.0 will be downloaded and installed.
mtl-2.1 will be downloaded and installed.
deepseq-1.3.0.0 will be downloaded and installed.
text-0.11.2.0 will be downloaded and installed.
parsec-3.1.2 will be downloaded and installed.
network-2.3.0.11 will be downloaded and installed.
time is already installed and the version is ok.
HTTP-4000.2.3 will be downloaded and installed.
zlib-0.5.3.3 will be downloaded and installed.
random is already installed and the version is ok.

Downloading Cabal-1.14.0...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  270k  100  270k    0     0   392k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  443k
ghc: could not execute: /usr/lib/distcc/bin/gcc

Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
Compiling the Setup script failed
```

Comment: Looks like its trying to use distcc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like ghc is configured to use distcc version of gcc. I don't know Arch Linux too much so I can't check this but maybe it was build with "--with-gcc=/usr/lib/distcc/bin/gcc" or something like this. This should be fixed by installing distcc.